# Is there a way to shorten an HTTP response from PHP?

Tags: php, http, get

I am working with an embedded data acquisition system that uses a Telit GSM modem to transmit sensor data to the web. I'm currently sending the data to a php script with a simple GET request. The issue I'm having is that the HTTP response is fairly large (~220 bytes). I have a very cheap 8Mb/mo data plan currently and am trying to minimize the bytes required for each transmission. I've considered compressing some of the outgoing data, but the potential gain there is fairly small. Since the response is of no use, other than to indicate that the request was successful (and I don't even parse this or use it), I would love to either cut it our or at least shorten it (simply the response code for example).

Does anyone know how to do this from PHP? I have looked into the header() function with no avail so far. The other option I considered was sending the request to a server program (say port 15000 instead of 80) and then making another request to my php script from there but this seems janky. I don't have the proper libraries on the student server I am using to access mysql and I am using phpCurl as well, otherwise I could use a simple server program for the whole thing.

Any ideas? Our server is running PHP Version 5.4.4

Luke

Comment: How many requests do you think you're going to get per month? Because you've still got room for like 40k.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Can you instead send data via TCP connection? Of course, in this case, I assume you have your own server computer. I wrote a simple TCP server using Twisted in Python to talk to my Telit GM862-GPS modules. Then you can code your TCP server to upload it to elsewhere.

If you are uploading the data to some other's website like twitter, I do not think you have many options to minimize the size.

Comment: This way old, never properly upvoted/selected this answer. This is what I ended up doing and it worked well. I think if I were to do it again I would use MQTT (as Xorlev suggested). I have since implemented it for a different project and really like it.

Answer (score 1):

To shorten your response I'd check the HTTP server its self. That being said, you're not going to get too much smaller.

I might look into [MQTT](http://mqtt.org/) for sensor transmission, it's a very lightweight protocol.

Comment: I think this is the best way to go about it, though there are also some other cool lightweight protocols out there.

Answer (score 0):

Once your PHP script has done its work, you should be able to simply tell it to:

```
die();
```

or

```
$status = 1;
die($status);
```

Then you can look for a numeric status (or simply a 200 response from the server). You may have to check the code to ensure that response data isn't being output elsewhere in the code before you catch it. Output buffering might help - https://www.php.net/manual/en/ref.outcontrol.php

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps you can host some application that implements a listening socket that your device sends its data to?

You can make up some read-only protocol using a delimiter, or a prefix indicating the message size. This way you can only send the data you want, without any overhead (like HTTP has).